# Unsure about parse tree of PCFG

Tags: trees, parsers, tree-grammars

I'm new to build parse trees and I'm really unsure if I'm doing this right. So I have this example Grammar (S->Sa, S->aSa, S->a) and the word I'm parsing is simply aaaa.

My solution would look like

[image: My Solution]

Is this right and is this the only possible parse tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tree is correct. However, it's not the only possible one. Your tree came from the derivation
$$
S\Rightarrow Sa\Rightarrow aSaa\Rightarrow aaaa
$$
a different one would be from
$$
S\Rightarrow aSa\Rightarrow aSaa\Rightarrow aaaa
$$